# Equality of the automorphism group of a graph and its complement

Tags: graph-theory

How can I show that the automorphism group of a graph $G$ is equal to the automorphism group of the complement of $G$?

Comment: Well, there's one obvious candidate for an isomorphism between them. Have you checked whether it is in fact an isomorphism?

Comment: @ChrisEagle I'm sorry, it is supposed to be equality, not isomorphism, i will correct that

Comment: So you already know what the isomorphism is (it is the identity). That should make things easier. What have you tried?

Comment: @ChrisEagle I haven't really _tried_ anything, I don't know _how_ to think about a problem like this. I though it might have something to do with adjacency matrices but I couldn't see how. So I don't know really - I turn to MSE in desperation :)

Comment: @hannahh, consideration of adjacency matrix would make it hard. You can think about how can an automorphism of a graph induces an automorphism of its complement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An automorphism of a graph preserves adjacency, and preserves non-adjacency in the meantime.

Comment: I think I get it now, thanks!